# ¿Cómo mostrar resultados con un condicional?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo este código para hacer búsqueda mediante parámetros preparados.

Quiero ponerle una condicional que me diga que no hay resultado, ya que así como está cuando no hay resultado sólo muestra pantalla en blanco y cuando hay resultado pues sí me lo muestra.

He intentado de muchas formas ejemplos que consigo pero nada me corre, intenté con `if($result->num_rows==0)` pero con eso me dice que no hay resultado todo el tiempo:

```
<?php
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];

include ('conectar.php');

$sql="SELECT monto, pista FROM datos where nombre= ?";
$resultado=mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
$ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado,"s", $nombre);
$ok=mysqli_stmt_execute ($resultado);
if($ok==false)
{

 echo"no hay nada we error";
}else{

  $ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado, $monto, $pista);


  echo"articulos encontrados <br><br>";

  while($total=mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)){

 echo" ".$monto ." ". $pista . "<br>";
}

mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta sentencia [`mysqli_stmt_execute ($resultado);`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) devuelve `true`cuando se ejecuta la consulta satisfactoriamente lo cual no significa que haya encontrado resultados, la consulta puede ser satisfactoria pero no devolver ningún valor por que no existe.

Lo que podrías hacer es consultar el número de filas afectadas y en el caso de ser mayor que cero, es por que se han encontrado resultados.

Para consultar el número de filas, primero hay que almacenar el resultado por medio de la función [`mysqli_stmt_store_result($resultado)`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) para luego recuperarla con [`mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

El siguiente código debería funcionarte bien:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

include('conectar.php');

$sql="SELECT monto, pista FROM datos where nombre= ?";
$resultado = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "s", $nombre);
mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($resultado);

if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado, $monto, $pista);
    echo "articulos encontrados <br><br>";

    while ($total = mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)) {

        echo" ".$monto ." ". $pista . "<br>";
    }
} else {

    echo "no hay nada we error";
}


mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
```

Comment: gracias hermano ayer pase casi todo el día con ese problema y no conseguía la manera de arreglar eso, estoy nuevo con todo esto de verdad gracias tienes 20 de 10 :D

Answer (score 0):

Primero tendrás que asignarle a resultado las filas, para eso en vez de usar `mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)` que crea un array con todos los valores, deberás utilizar la siguiente sintaxis 
 `$numero_de_filas = $resultado->num_rows;`

Eso devolverá el número de filas de la base de datos, es decir, un número que le asignará a la variable `$numero_de_filas` que podrás comparar en el if